# Keeping A jQuery menu open with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I've been playing around with some of the jQuery cookies I've found across this site and the cookie I think is working but my menu stops opening altogether.

I'm very new to jQuery so not sure where I could be going wrong.

I just went to keep open the links e.g click link 1 and then a sub-menu item and when the page loads, link 1 is still open.

Someone please point me in the right direction!

Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/pHgB7/

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a>Link</a>

</li>
<li class="drop"><a>Link 1</a>

    <ul id="m1">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1 Item</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1 Item</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="drop"><a>Link 2</a>

    <ul id="m2">
        <li><a href="#">Link 2 Item</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2 Item</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="drop"><a>Link 3</a>

    <ul id="m3">
        <li><a href="#">Link 3 Item</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3 Item</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
jQuery(function ($) {
// jQuery code in here can safely use $
$('.nav li')
.css({
cursor: "pointer"
})
$(".drop")
    .on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
})

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little messier answer:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // jQuery code in here can safely use $
    $('.nav li')
        .css({
            cursor: "pointer"
        });

    $(".drop")
        .on('click', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $(this).find('ul').toggle();
            $.cookie('open_items', 'the_value');
            openItems = new Array();
            $("li.drop").each(function(index, item) {
                if ($(item).hasClass('open')) {
                    openItems.push(index);
                }
            });
            $.cookie('open_items', openItems.join(','));
        });

    if( $.cookie('open_items') && $.cookie('open_items').length > 0 ) {
        previouslyOpenItems = $.cookie('open_items');
        openItemIndexes = previouslyOpenItems.split(',');
        $(openItemIndexes).each(function(index, item) {
            $("li.drop").eq(item).addClass('open').find('ul').toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

You'll need to include the [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) library for this.

Updated fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/pHgB7/2/

Comment: Thank you very much it worked a treat after I served the jquery library.

Any chance you could explain what is going, so I can learn from it?
Also is there a way to set it to expire say after an hour? 

Thanks again

Comment: Just been playing around with it and it seems when you actually click a menu item it closes the menu? Would like that to stay open after you clicked a item. But other than that it works great!