# Keeping A jQuery menu open on refresh or on click with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

am trying to make this dropdown menu of https://ionianbookstore.com/ staying active click of submenu or refresh but it doesnt work.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396116/keeping-a-jquery-menu-open-with-cookies#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396116/keeping-a-jquery-menu-open-with-cookies#_=_)
This one helped me, changed the code to my plugin code but still doesnt work, i know i didnt make it correct so thats why i open a new question in order to someone help :)

The .js of plugin is this one :

```
!function(e){function n(e){e.hasClass("toggle__open")?e.removeClass("toggle__open"):e.addClass("toggle__open"),e.parent(".link__wrap").parent(".menu-item").children(".sub-menu").slideToggle("fast")}e(document).on("click",".easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler",function(t){n(e(this)),t.preventDefault(),t.stopPropagation()})}(jQuery);
```

Here is the solution from another question (this one i used to make it work but i didnt make it)
http://jsfiddle.net/pHgB7/2/

Thanks for help even for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

try to stop the propagation on the clicked children of your side menu.

```
  $("#yoursidemenu li a")
    .on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can understand all you have to do is trigger the below on the `easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler` element of which you want to toggle.

```
e.addClass("toggle__open"), e.parent(".link__wrap").parent(".menu-item").children(".sub-menu").slideToggle("fast")
```

So you can add an attribute on the element and then setup a cookie to know which one you'd like to open after the refresh on each click

```
<a href="#" class="easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler" data-toggle="history"><li>...</li></a>

$(function(){
    $('.easy-sidebar-menu-widget-toggler').on('click',function(){
        //Setup the cookie on click here
        $.cookies('myToggle',$(this).data('history'));
    });

    //then on the init of the page you can do
    //a check and if the cookie exists then toggle fine the 
    //a href and then toggle it.
    if($.cookies('myToggle'))
    {
        var toToogle = $.cookies('myToggle');
        var aToToggle = $('body').find('a[data-toggle="'+ toToggle + '"');
        aToToggle.addClass('toggle__open');
        aToToggle.parent(".link__wrap").parent(".menu-item").children(".sub-menu").slideToggle("fast");
    }
});
```

Don't forget, you'll need to implement some logic to remove the cookie if the user clicks on a menu without a toggler.